# What's alternative choice for background worker, async defered task queue in django/wsgi besides celery?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, task-queue

Are there any pure wsgi implementation of background task?

I want to use local variables under the same context directly, not serialize/deserialize to another daemon process via a broker.

Is it possible to make this happen under the current wsgi infrastructure? E.g. after return response yield, run some callback functions?

Comment: "pure wsgi", do you mean pure Python?

Comment: yes, python, without external brokers

Comment: @est so then, may I ask: are you not actually looking for solutions leveraging Django? or do you mean "I don't want to run any non-webserver processes"?

Comment: @fish2000 What other options do we have besides django? I don't mind worker process, I just hate to serialize and de-serialize data back and fourth. I want to do the task under the same process, in another threaded of fork a subprocess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of question asked on the Python WEB-SIG. I reference the same page as provided in response to the question on the Python WEB-SIG so others can see it:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/RegisteringCleanupCode

In doing this though, it ties up the request thread and so it would not be able to handle other requests until your task has finished.

Creating background threads at the end of a request is not a good idea unless you do it using a pooling mechanism such that you limit the number of worker threads for your tasks. Because the process can crash or be shutdown, you loose the job as only in memory and thus not persistent.

Better to use Celery, or if you think that is too heavy weight, have a look at Redis Queue (RQ) instead.

Comment: Did expect you show here on SO. Thanks man! You are awesome! By Redis Queue, did you mean [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub/), or [RedisMQ](http://restmq.com)? I think both only support primitive serializable data type to be handled by the task worker. I really prefer a fork/thread way to do that. It's more native and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at Django async. It uses an in-database queue and so handles transactions much better. All arguments need to be JSONable as does the return type. In some cases this means you may need to schedule a wrapper function, but that oughtn't to cause you any headaches.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-async

You don't want to be doing this sort of thing inside the web server -- it's absolutely not the right place to do it. Django async provides a manage.py command for flushing the queue which you can run in a loop, possible on another machine from the web server.